# function help in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I am going to be reusing this code several times so I would like to use this. function. I'm not sure how the pointers work with this. My goal is to check if `mneumonic` is equal to any of the values in `strings_label_table`. If `mneumonic` is equal to one of the values I wanna set `string_equal_flag = 1` and return it and if not set `return string_not_flag = 1;` and return it. Or could I just set it from the function? This works perfectly in my main.

```
char *strings_label_table[503] = {0};
char *strings_mneumonic_table[503] = {0};
char mneumonic[20] = {0};

int hashLetter(char mneumonic)
            for(i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                //printf(" i is %d \n", i);
                if(strings_label_table[i] != NULL)
                {
                    if(strcmp (strings_label_table[i], mneumonic) == 0)
                    {
                        printf(" strings_label_table[i] is equal\n");
                        printf(" strings_label_table[i] is %s \n", strings_label_table[i]);
                        //printf(" nam is %s \n", nam);
                        return string_equal_flag = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                    //printf(" Top if 2 \n");
                }
                if(i == 49)
                {
                    return string_not_flag = 1;
                    //printf(" set string_not_flag\n"); 
                }
            }
```

Comment: Please try to compile it. Seems there are some type mismatches. Let your compiler show you all warnings, and handle them. Come back with corrected code.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to understand what you are trying to do with this function. These are my comments:

```
 int hashLetter(const char *mneumonic) 
                    /* the func argument needs to be a char pointer,
                     * not just one char
                     */
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
         if (strings_label_table[i] != NULL) {
             if(strcmp (strings_label_table[i], mneumonic) == 0) {
                 printf(" strings_label_table[i] is equal\n");
                 printf(" strings_label_table[i] is %s \n", strings_label_table[i]);
                 //printf(" nam is %s \n", nam);
                 return string_equal_flag = 1;   /* returns 1 */
             }
             //printf(" Top if 2 \n");
         }
     }
     /* You can just return after the loop */
     return string_not_flag = 1;  /* returns 1 */
 }
```

Note, this function always returns one, so not much sense in returning values at all. Might as well be void.

```
   return string_equal_flag = 1;
   /*  Is the same as */
   return (string_equal_flag = 1);
```

Where the expression `string_equal_flag = 1` evaluates to `1`

Answer (score 0):

I see the following problems in your code.

**Body of the function**

Body of the function is not properly defined. You need to have the body of the function between a `{` and a `}`.

```
 int hashLetter(char mneumonic)
 {
    // Body of the function must be contained between the braces, {}.
 }
```

**Input to the function**

You have

```
char mneumonic[20] = {0};
```

above the function definition. The function also has an argument named `mneumonic`, which is of different type. I don't think you need the one above the function definition. I also think, judging by the way you are trying to use it in your function, that you probably meant the argument to the function to be of type `char*` or `const char*`.

**Code in the functon**

You have

```
return string_equal_flag = 1;
break;
```

You don't need the `break` statement after the `return`. It will never be executed. Also, you don't need the additional assignment for the return to work. You can replace those two lines with:

```
return 1;
```

Also, you don't need the block

```
if(i == 49)
{
    return string_not_flag = 1;
    //printf(" set string_not_flag\n"); 
}
```

If you have not returned from the function when the `for` loop ends, then you know that you did not find the mnemonic. You can simply return 0.

In summary, the function can be simplified to look like:

```
int hashLetter(const char* mneumonic)
{
   int i = 0;
   for(i = 0; i < 50; i++)
   {
      if(strings_label_table[i] != NULL)
      {
         if(strcmp (strings_label_table[i], mneumonic) == 0)
         {
            return 1;
         }
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few problems with your code that'll prevent it from compiling, and I'm not sure I understood what you are trying to do. However, if you are trying to use a memorized word (like "Sally") to lookup a word you are trying to memorize (like "Subtraction"), in a mnemonic like "Please Excuse My Dear Aunt Sally", then here's one way of implementing it:

### Implementation

```
#include <string.h>

//Try not to hardcode values (like '50', '20', or '49')
//Instead, put them into constants so if you ever change the value,
//you won't accidentally miss any usages.
const int WordSize = 32;

//Values that belong together should stay together, preferably by putting them in a structure.
typedef struct MnemonicWordStruct
{
    char originalWord[32];
    char memorizedWord[32];
} MnemonicWord;

const char *GetWordFromMnemonic(const char *memorizedWord, MnemonicWord *mnemonicWords, int numMnemonicWords)
{ // Don't forget the opening bracket!

    //Iterate over each mnemonic work, looking for a match.
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < numMnemonicWords; ++i)
    {
        //Compare this mnemonic's memorized word to the memorized word we passed into the function.
        if(strcmp(mnemonicWords[i].memorizedWord, memorizedWord) == 0)
        {
            //If it matches, return the actual word.
            return mnemonicWords[i].originalWord;
        }
    }

    //If we haven't found a match, return NULL.
    return NULL;
}
```

### Usage

Here's an example of how it can be used:

```
int main()
{
    const int NumMnemonicWords = 6;
    MnemonicWord mnemonicWords[6];

    strcpy(mnemonicWords[0].originalWord, "Paranthesis");
    strcpy(mnemonicWords[0].memorizedWord, "Please");

    strcpy(mnemonicWords[1].originalWord, "Exponents");
    strcpy(mnemonicWords[1].memorizedWord, "Excuse");

    strcpy(mnemonicWords[2].originalWord, "Multiplication");
    strcpy(mnemonicWords[2].memorizedWord, "My");

    strcpy(mnemonicWords[3].originalWord, "Division");
    strcpy(mnemonicWords[3].memorizedWord, "Dear");

    strcpy(mnemonicWords[4].originalWord, "Addition");
    strcpy(mnemonicWords[4].memorizedWord, "Aunt");

    strcpy(mnemonicWords[5].originalWord, "Subtraction");
    strcpy(mnemonicWords[5].memorizedWord, "Sally");

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < NumMnemonicWords; ++i)
    {
        const char *lookup = mnemonicWords[i].memorizedWord;
        const char *answer = GetWordFromMnemonic(lookup, mnemonicWords, NumMnemonicWords);
        printf("%s = %s\n", lookup, answer);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And here's the compilable, functional, code on Ideone.com where you can actually test it and play with it:

### [Working code](http://ideone.com/Y4YgJq)